# Magento allowed currencies list

Tags: magento

In my Magento backend, I am not seeing any allowed currencies beyond the 3 I have already set up. Any ideas why?

Comment: Where did you see these currencies, you can setup your currencies under System -> Configuration -> General -> Currency setup.. If you see here and only 3 currencies are displayed, make sure that you selected the `Current Configuration Scope:` as Default config and not anything else..

Comment: Thanks - yes, that is exactly where I am: System > Configuration > General > Currency Setup, and Configuration Scope near the top left is 'Default Config'. Am out of ideas.. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of possible currencies ultimately comes from the many XML files in `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data`, in particular `root.xml` is always consulted. Check this folder exists and contains about 400 or more of these files. Also, check they are all readable to web user on your server.

<sub>The file `\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Locale\Config.php` is probably only used for default values during installation or setup.</sub>

Comment: Did a quick check, that folder exists (755) and .xml files inside are 644 so permissions appear to be okay. I'll try to overwrite that entire folder from the original Magento archive...

Comment: Update: nope, didn't work. Uploaded 476 fresh files into that directory, but I still only see 3 Allowed Currencies.

Comment: I clicked around and found something under Advanced > System > Currency. In here, for some reason there is a Currency tab - I expanded it and saw Installed Currencies and there were only 3 currencies selected! So, clicking and selecting more 'installed currencies' seems to have solved my problem: I can now select more currencies under General > Currency Setup.

Comment: Had the same problem and "fixed" it same as lee - Advanced > System > Currency. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try Admin->Configuration->System->Currency->Installed Currencies.
I bet only the 3 are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Locale\Config.php` and it should have all the currencies ...

If anything is deleted try adding a new currency here and it will display it in the admin.

If you need a complete currency list , download only this file from magento and replace them.

Comment: Thanks again, I double checked that file - appeared ok but just in case I downloaded the original archive online (1.4.1.1) and extracted & overwrote that file. Doesn't appear to have made a difference. I can see all the currencies inside the file. Also I don't think I have anything overriding it because I don't have a /app/code/local/Mage/Core folder... is something else going on here?